# Facing issue for synchronous operation in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, bluebird

Below code have 2 files and having client.js which calls to server file but didn't get the synchronous output.
I tried with promise, bluebird, async_await but didn't get success.
Expected output is a sequence of the alphabet in a console.

Do not use settimout.

Understanding of files.
server.js : server file is having NodeAPI which content only routing.

Client.js : logic which tried is in this file

You need to use two console, first run server.js and second console need to run client.js and output will be print in server.js console.

```
 Expecting output is 
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e

 /////////////////server.js/////////////////
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));

    app.post('/', function (req, res) {   
       console.log(req.body.test)
       res.status(200).send('ok');
    });

    var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log('ok');
    });

    //////////////client.js///////////////////


    //var Promise = require('bluebird');
    var request = require('request');
    console.log('server file called');
    var array_data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];


    // var promises = [];
    // for(let i = 0; i < array_data.length; i++) {
    //     var promise = request.post({url: 'http://localhost:3000',form : {key:array_data[i]}});
    // }

    // var page = 0;
    // var last_page = array_data.length;

    // (function loop() {
    //     if (page < last_page) {
    //         request.post({
    //             url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    //             form: 'test=' + array_data[page]
    //         }, function (error, response, body) {
    //             page++;
    //             loop();
    //         });
    //     }
    // }());


    // async function loopAsync() {
    //     for (let i = 0; i < array_data.length; i++) {
    //         await request.post({
    //             url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    //             form: 'test=' + array_data[i]
    //         });
    //     }
    // }
    // loopAsync();

    async function loopAsync() {
        var page = 0;
        var last_page = array_data.length;
        while (page < last_page) {
            await request.post({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000',
                form: 'test=' + array_data[page]
            });
            page++;
        }
    }
    loopAsync();


[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVlut.png
```

Comment: you can use await with promises so use request-promise
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise#request-promise

Comment: Hi @Ariz, I already tried with promise request but didn't get success.

Comment: @Ariz is right, you can only use await with a function that returns a promise, request on its own won't do that. Can you share the code you used with request-promise?

Comment: The first thing I would do is use NPM debugging break points to assure that the requests are being dispatched in the expected order, this would rule out any issue with the client.

Answer (score 2):

You can use util.promisify.

Here is sample code

```
const reqpost = util.promisify(request.post); 

async function loopAsync() {
    var page = 0;
    var last_page = array_data.length;
    while (page < last_page) {
      await reqpost({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        form: 'test=' + array_data[page]
      });
     page++;
 } } 

loopAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

`request.post` is a function that takes request options and a callback like this.

```
function request(letter, callback = () => {}) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(letter);
        callback();
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
}
```

What you're doing is calling that function without supplying a callback:

```
async function clientWithRequest() {
    const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    for(let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        await request(letters[i]);
    }
}
```

here, the requests are all fired off at the same time and will return in an indeterminate order.

What you need to do if you want to use async is make your request return a promise. Under the hood, await is really just doing request.then(somethingElse()). So if you change your request to return a promise like:

```
function requestPromise(letter) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(letter);
            resolve();
        }, Math.random() * 1000);
    });
}
```

your await code will then work as expected. Effectively it's doing.

`request('a').then(() => request('b')).then(() => request('c'));`

Comment: setTimeout is not allow to use, its not get proper response as per server operation

Comment: @nigammehta Will Munn gave that as an example to prove his point for asynchronus operation. If you want to use async and await wrap yourrequest.post function inside a promise as shown in the example

Comment: Yes, it's just an example, and as @Joseph Persie said in his answer, you can use promisify with request.post to acheive this or alternatively use the request-promise module

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/request/request#forms

Since you are forming the form data string yourself via Node

Is it possible that if you can just let `request` help you form the encoded string via their form method?

```js
const jobs = [];
const array_data = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
];
require('request');
const request = require('request-promise');
async function loopAsync() {
  for(const char of array_data) {
    jobs.push(
      request.post({
          url: 'https://marble-scene.glitch.me/',
          form: {
            test: char
          }
      })
    );
  }
  const output = await Promise.all(jobs);
  output.forEach(char => console.log(char)); // # a b c d e
}
loopAsync();
```

[Edit]

Just edit the `client.js` code, fixed the silly syntax error inside the `jobs.push` block

Working prove: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/marble-scene

Comment: As provided your answer is not getting proper output, it seems same as past which I shared my code

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to importing additional libraries. you can simply "promisify" the callback dependent `request.post` method.

```
async function loopAsync() {
        var page = 0;
        var last_page = array_data.length;
        while (page < last_page) {
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                request.post({
                  url: 'http://localhost:3000',
                  form: 'test=' + array_data[page]
                 }, function(err,httpResponse,body){
                   if (err) reject(err);
                   else resolve({httpResponse,body});
                 });
                 page++;
            });
        }
}
loopAsync()
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is valid but wants depth understanding which you used async_await with promise, Could you please share the details?

Comment: @nigammehta The `await` construct expects a promise which `request.post` does not return. By wrapping it in a `Promise` invocation function, you turn it into a function that returns a promise which in turn is expected by the `await` construct.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the depth of request promise.

Comment: Insted of this I used request-promise library for it and got another solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I did the R&D, request module is not returned promise so for that need to use request-promise library.

```
let request = require('request');
    let rp = require('request-promise');
    var array_data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];    
    //with the use of request-promise library 
        async function loopAsync() {
            var page = 0;
            var last_page = array_data.length;
            while (page < last_page) {
                var options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
                    body: {
                        test: array_data[page]
                    },
                    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
                };
                await rp(options);
                page++;
            }
        }
        loopAsync();
```